# Candidate in finding majority element in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

**I am not asking how to find the majority element in an array**, which has been discussed at length here [Find majority element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325200/find-majority-element-in-array)

My problem is as below:

There is an array `arr[1...2n]`, the majority element of this array is `maj`, now I will use the following rule to delete elements in `arr`,

if `arr[i] == arr[i + 1]`, delete `arr[i]`, i = 1, 3, 5,..., 2n - 1;
else if `arr[i] != arr[i + 1]`, delete both `arr[i]` and `arr[i + 1]`, i = 1, 3, 5, ..., 2n - 1.

then we can get a new array `new_arr`, and candidate of the majority element for `new_arr` is `new_maj`,
is there any proof to prove that `new_maj == maj`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a proof.

We are only interested in element pairs `a[i],a[i+1]`, `i` odd. If `a[i]=a[i+1]`, we call such a pair "good". Other pairs are "bad". Elements that are equal to the majority candidate are "groovy". A good pair of groovy elements is a groovy pair.

The simple fact about good pairs is that at least one half of good pairs are groovy. Suppose it is not so; then among good pairs, strictly less than one half of elements are groovy, and among bad pairs, no more than one half of elements are groovy. In total, strictly less than one half of elements are groovy. This is a contradiction.

So we have established that at least one half of good pairs are groovy.

Now eliminate all bad pairs. Still at least one half of all elements are groovy (because only good pairs remain, and among those, at least one half are groovy).

Now eliminate every other element from good pairs. Still at least one half of all elements are groovy (because amount of each element is simply halved).

This concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Define `N = 2 n`.  The array contains `N` elements.

Define `M` as the number of times `maj` appears in the array.  The definition of “majority element” is that `M > N/2`.

Now divide the array into pairs `p[1] ... p[n]`.  Define `q0` as the number of pairs that contain zero instances of `maj`.  Define `q1` as the number of pairs that contain exactly one instance of `maj`.  Define `q2` as the number of pairs that contain exactly two instances of `maj`.

Then `N = 2 q0 + 2 q1 + 2 q2` and `M = q1 + 2 q2`.

Substitute into the inequality defining the majority element, and simplify:

```
        M > N / 2
q1 + 2 q2 > (2 q0 + 2 q1 + 2 q2) / 2
q1 + 2 q2 > q0 + q1 + q2
     2 q2 > q0 + q2
       q2 > q0
```

So the number of pairs containing two instances of `maj` exceeds the number of pairs containing zero instances of `maj`.

Now define `M'` to be the number of times `maj` appears in the new array, after running your algorithm.  The algorithm deletes one `maj` for each `q1` pair, and one `maj` for each `q2` pair.  So `M' = M - q1 - q2`.

Define `N'` to be the size of the new array produced by the algorithm.  The algorithm deletes two elements for each `q1` pair, and one element for each `q2` pair.

But we don't know how many elements the algorithm deletes for each `q0` pair.  Some of the `q0` pairs contain two different elements, and the algorithm deletes both.  But the other `q0` pairs contain identical (non-`maj`) elements, and the algorithm deletes only one.

One extreme is that all of the `q0` pairs are deleted entirely.  In that case, the algorithm deletes `2 q0` elements, so

```
N - 2 q1 - q2 - 2 q0 ≤ N'
```

The other extreme is that only one element is deleted from each `q0` pair.  In that case, the algorithm deletes `q0` elements, so

```
N - 2 q1 - q2 - q0 ≥ N'
```

Let's go back to the definition of “majority element” and do some algebra:

```
          M > N / 2
M - q1 - q2 > N / 2 - q1 - q2
M - q1 - q2 > (N - 2 q1 - 2 q2) / 2
M - q1 - q2 > (N - 2 q1 - q2 - q2) / 2
```

The left-hand side is `M'`.

```
M' > (N - 2 q1 - q2 - q2) / 2
```

Can we turn the right-hand side into `N' / 2`?  First, multiply both sides by 2:

```
2 M' > N - 2 q1 - q2 - q2
```

Recall that we proved `q2 > q0`.  Therefore

```
2 M' > N - 2 q1 - q2 - q2 > N - 2 q1 - q2 - q0
```

and, since we deduced `N - 2 q1 - q2 - q0 ≥ N'`,

```
2 M' > N - 2 q1 - q2 - q0 ≥ N'
```

so

```
2 M' > N'
  M' > N' / 2
```

Thus `maj` appears sufficient times in the new array to be the majority element of the new array.  QED.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my variant of the proof:

Consider the 4 cases for pairs arr[i] and arr[i+1] (or vice versa, order with the pair is not important), i is odd. Let **maj** be the major element and **min** is any minor element:

1. **maj**  **maj** - let the number of such pairs be *a*
2. **maj**  **min** - let the number of such pairs be *b*
3. **min1**  **min2** - let the number of such pairs be *c*, min1 != min2
4. **min1**  **min1** - let the number of such pairs be *d*

a, b, c, d are all >= 0.

Case 1 contributes 2 to the original sum of major elements |maj| and decreases the final sum of major elements |maj|' (after execution of the algorithm) by 1

Case 2 contributes 1 to |maj| and 1 to |min|, the original sum of all minor elements, and decreases |maj|' by 1 and |min|' by 1

Case 3 contributes 2 to |min| and decreases |min|' by 2

Case 4 contributes 2 to |min| and decreases |min|' by 1

Therefore, the total number of major elements in the original array arr[] is:

```
|maj| = 2a + b
```

While the number of all minor elements is:

```
|min| = b + 2c + 2d
```

Since |maj| > |min| ,

```
2a + b > b + 2c + 2d
    2a > 2c + 2d
     a > c + d
```

After running the algorithm, the new number of major elements is given by:

```
|maj|' = |maj| - a - b
```

and the new number of minor elements is:

```
|min|' = |min| - b - 2c - d
```

Substituting we get:

```
|maj|' = 2a + b - a - b           = a
|min|' = b + 2c + 2d - b - 2c - d = d
```

Since we know from above that c + d < a, and a, c, d are all >= 0, we have

```
a > c + d =>
a > d =>
|maj|' > |min|'
```

Therefore **maj** is still the major element in the new array.