# Write an algorithm that returns the majority element in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.5, divide-and-conquer

> 9. (10 points) Write an O(nlogn) algorithm to find the majority element of a list of items. (Assume that the number of elements is a power of 2). Again, the only operation you can use on items of the list is equality comparison. Hint: solve a problem of size n by solving two sub-problems of size n/2

This was a test question on divide and conquer, for my algorithms class.
Here is the code I wrote in python 3.5.

```
def majElement(L):
    tally = 0
    if len(L) == 1:
        return 1
    for i in range(len(L)):
        tally = majElement(L[i:len(L)]) + majElement(L[len(L)/2:])

        if tally > (len(L)/2):
            print(L[i])
```

This code results in a stack overflow. Some how I'm not reaching my base case. 
How can I stop the infinite recursive calls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find majority element in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325200/find-majority-element-in-array)

Comment: That question was for O(n) time, which since O(nlogn) is larger than that, it still works.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the divide and conquer approach, but majority element in an array/list can be identified in `O(nlogn)` time.

This can be done using a `binary search tree` using structure

```
struct tree
{
  int element;
  int count;
}BST;
```

*Algorithm*:

1. Insert elements in `BST` one by one and if already present then increment the count of the node.
2. At any stage, if count of a node becomes more than `n/2` then return.

Now, the worst case complexity can be `O(n^2)` in case of skewed BST. So, use a `self balancing BST` to ensure `O(nlogn)` time.

If you want to do it using **Divide and Conquer** approach,

*Algorithm* :

1. Divide array into two parts L and R.
2. int m1 = Majority(L); int m2 = Majority(R);
3. if m1 is majority return it.
4. if m2 is majority retun it.
5. Otherwise return "no majority element".

*Code* :

i=0;j=arr.length;

```
int majority(int *A, int i, int j)
{
    int m1= majority(A, i, j/2-1);
    int m2= majority(A, j/2+1, j);
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<j; i++)
        if(A[i] == m1)
            count++;
    if(count > j/2)
        return m1;
    count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<j; i++)
        if(A[i] == m2)
            count++;
    if(count > j/2)
        return m2;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I think the question was asking for a Python solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you are only *returning* a value in the base case; the rest of the time, you print a value and return `None`.

Second, the first recursive call is made when `i == 0`, which means `L[i:len(L)]` is the same as `L`, so you aren't acutually reducing the size of the problem. At the very least, you want `for i in range(1, len(L))`, but I suspect you aren't properly decomposing the problem into subproblems. (You shouldn't have to make as many recursive calls as you are proposing.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your algorithm works,
mine does the implementation of finding majority element using *divide and conquer* technique. It divides the array into two slices and checks for potential candidate. It is then checked that whether it is majority element or not.

```
def divideAndConquer(array): #Function to solve by divide and conquer
    if(len(array)==1):
        return array[0]
    middle = len(array)//2
    left = array[:middle] #First half
    right = array[middle:] #Second half
    cLeft = divideAndConquer(left) #candidate for left side
    cRight = divideAndConquer(right) #candidate for right side
    if cLeft == cRight: #if both have the same candidate, it is the one
        return cLeft
    if array.count(cLeft)>middle: #if not, check in left
        return cLeft
    if array.count(cRight)>middle: #else check in right
        return cRight
    return "No majority element" #no majority element
```